# Why does XmlDocument.Load(String) seem to want read-write access?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

According to MSDN the .NET [XmlDocument.Load(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx) method requires *write* access to the underlying file.  The exceptions list says

```
UnauthorizedAccessException :  filename specified a file that is read-only....
```

My question boils down to

- Is it even true that read-write access is needed, or is this just a documentation error?
- Does it mean that the file is kept open during the lifetime of the object?
- Does it mean that modifications to the the XmlDocument and its sub-nodes can result in live modifications to the file on disk?  Even without an explicit save.

Comment: I think it is a documentation error, cause when i deny `Write` in the Security settings or set the `ReadOnly`-Attribute of a file, the document is successfully loaded by the method. I only get the exception when i explicitly deny `Read`

Comment: Looks like a documentation error. I can load read-only documents with no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it even true that read-write access is needed

- Looks like documentation bug. When loading, `XmlDocument` creates `XmlReader`, which, AFAIK, doesn't throws such exceptions.

> Does it mean that the file is kept open during the lifetime of the object

- No, file becomes closed after reading.

> Does it mean that modifications to the the XmlDocument and its sub-nodes can result in live modifications to the file on disk

- No, because the file is closed.

Answer (score 0):

with `async` attribute set to `False` as in `XDoc.async = False` , the read-only xml does not get loaded into DOM object

[async Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms761398(v%3Dvs.85))